# How to clone Azure git repository using username and password?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to clone a git repository from azure devops but when I run the following command the authentication fails.

```
git clone https://myazuredevopsemail:myazuredevopspassword@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/RepoName/_git/RepoName
```

Am I doing this wrong? How can I clone using only my visualstudio.com credentials? I assume this must be possible because when I exclude the username (email) and password from the above url and simply do a git clone, a 'git credentials' pop-up opens up and I am able to successfully login with my email and password.

Please note that I cannot use Personal Access Tokens or SSH keys for my use-case, since PATs and SSH keys are per-organization in the azure devops authentication model. Whereas I'm writing a script that runs the git clone command for many different organizations (all of whom my visualstudio account has access to)

Comment: You can use SSH keys and you should use SSH keys. Please see this info on ssh config and multiple domains and SSH keys. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_mobile_application_platform_hosted/3/html/local_development_guide/using-multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-domainsprojects

Comment: @DerekWilliams Using SSH would require me to manually add my public key to all of the organizations, and as I mentioned in my question that's not possible for me due to the high number of organizations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `myazuredevopsemail` use your devops username.

The issue with the email address is it contains the `@` symbol and the URL decoder thinks that your email domain is the devops domain (and then is presented with another `@` for the actual devops domain).